# Constructing a new Pandas Dataframe using combined string and list as column headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to construct a new dataframe in Pandas.  The resulting dataframe will need to have departments as the index and date ranges across the top.  So far, I have the following:

```
#generate a list of years within report range
timeframes_yrs = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date, freq='12MS').strftime('%m/%d/%Y').tolist()
#create a new dataframe with columns named after the output of the list
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['department', list(timeframes_yrs)])
```

This appears to make a column for department (as expected), but then provides a column containing my entire list.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [department, [01/01/2017, 01/01/2018, 01/01/2019]]
```

Ideally, I want each of these to be columns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [department, 01/01/2017, 01/01/2018, 01/01/2019]
```

I have tried setting the words "departments" to a variable and passing that in with the same result.  I have also tried adjusting the syntax (brackets, parenthesis, etc.) with no success.

My question is - do I need to accomplish this with a "For" loop or adding the list first then appending the additional column later, or is there a way to accomplish this by passing the string and list into the Pandas dataframe upon creation as "columns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack your iterable containing date ranges using `*`, namely the [`iterable unpacking operator`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['department', *timeframes_yrs])
```

---

```
Columns: [department, 01/01/2017, 01/01/2018, 01/01/2019]
```

Comment: Thank you - this did exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs for [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) `columns` takes something array-like. Right now you're passing a list of dates **within** the list of columns so pandas thinks you only want two columns.  @rafaelc has a good way to create all of your columns.  You mentioned that you wanted the departments as the index so if that's the case try passing just the list of dates as columns and using a list of departments as the index:

```
departments = ['sales', 'marketing', 'it']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), index=departments, columns=(['a', 'b', 'c']))

           a  b  c
sales      1  2  3
marketing  4  5  6
it         7  8  9
```

Comment: While the first answer above got me to the desired state, this may actually help more with my next question which is around dynamically passing the values found back in.  I will experiment with this answer for sure.  Thank you!